# CSS Shimmer effect with blocking JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations, linear-gradients

I have a shimmer React component with the following CSS

```
background: #ebebeb;
background-image: linear-gradient(to right,  #ebebeb 0%, #c5c5c5 20%,  #ebebeb 40%,  #ebebeb 100%);
```

and the animation keyframe I apply to it is as follows:

```
{
    0%: { background-position: -468px 0 };
    100%: { background-position: 468px 0 };
}
```

My home page is quite heavy on mount. So the animation freezes for about a second or so.
I read that animating transition is done off-thread https://www.phpied.com/css-animations-off-the-ui-thread/

Can anyone help me do my shimmer effect in a similar off-thread manner?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use transform as suggested in the link. Here is an idea with pseudo element:

```css
.box {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #ebebeb calc(50% - 100px), #c5c5c5 50%, #ebebeb calc(50% + 100px));
  background-size:0;
  height: 200px;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.box::before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  width:calc(200% + 200px);
  bottom:0;
  background-image:inherit;
  animation:move 2s linear infinite; 
}
@keyframes move{
  to {
    transform:translateX(calc(50% + 100px));
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I just tried this, JS still blocks the animation.

https://jsfiddle.net/d3qb6z4a

Comment: @mohsinulhaq you are testing on a browser that doesn't support this. In the link you will read *In non-supporting browsers, which is most of them, the kill switch kills all the animations. Business as usual.*

Comment: I tried both of them in the same browser. When I open the example link in the article (http://www.phpied.com/files/css-thread/thread.html), cliking "kill 'em all for 2 sec" only stops the middle box, which is not using transform animation. So that means my browser (Chrome 77, macOS) supports it.
It's just that jsfiddle is not working.

Comment: @mohsinulhaq strange .. they should behave the same

Comment: @mohsinulhaq it's the use of percentage value .. if you consider only pixel value inside translate it will work

Comment: Ok, that works now. I will try to implement it using pixel values. Thanks a lot!
PS: I checked out your css-chalenges website. It's incredible!